# Pessimistic Lock while executing paginable query

Tags: java, sql, jpa, h2, jpql

**tl;dr How to write following query:**
`SELECT * FROM T_BATCH_DATA WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM T_BATCH_DATA OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY) FOR UPDATE ;` **using JPQL**?

I have a JPQL named query: `name=Foo.foo, query = "FROM Foo foo WHERE foo.modified<:date"`

which is supposed to retrieve paginated results and set lock to prevent concurrent reading by another POD. Below is the corresponding code:

```
findFooByLastInteractionUpdate(int pageIndex, int noOfRecords, LocalDateTime retentionDate) 
{
    return entityManager.createNamedQuery("Foo.foo", Foo.class)
                .setParameter("date", date) //
                .setFirstResult(pageIndex * noOfRecords) //
                .setMaxResults(noOfRecords) //
                .setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) //
                .getResultList();
}
```

The unit test is extremally simple and looks like this:

```
// given:
initializeDb();
LocalDateTime date = ...;

// when:
List<Foo> result = cut.findFooByLastInteractionUpdate(0, 3, date);

// then:
Assert.assertEquals(2, result.size());
```

And initialization method looks like this:

```
initializeDb() {
    getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO FOO (ID, ..., ..., ...) VALUES (1, ..., ..., ...)").executeUpdate();
}
```

However, when I execute this query the resulting logs are:
`javax.persistence.PessimisticLockException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002 (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: 
Syntax error in SQL statement ... FROM FOO WHERE (MODIFIED < ?) FOR UPDATE LIMIT[*] ? OFFSET ? "; 
SQL statement: SELECT FOO ... FROM FOO WHERE (MODIFIED < ?) FOR UPDATE LIMIT ? OFFSET ? [42000-196]
Error Code: 42000`

In H2 manual i found that 42000 code corresponds to syntax error.
Having access only to Oracle DB i tried to execute similar query by hand so:

`SELECT * FROM FOO FOR UPDATE FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY OFFSET 5 ROWS;`

which results in `ORA-02014`.

However I managed to rewrite the query in a way that executes successfully:

`SELECT * FROM T_BATCH_DATA WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM T_BATCH_DATA OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY) FOR UPDATE ;`

**How can I rewrite the JPQL query?**

Comment: IMO using FOR UPDATE is not possible in JPQL. Just use native SQL, this is the simplest solution. And so you still have other challenges ahead - threads will block while waiting for the locks to be released from other threads (tip: consider using `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` clause), and it will be very difficult if not possible at all for you to simulate Oracle's behaviour in H2. Not sure if `LIMIT ? OFFSET ? ` can be used in parametrized query (maybe in 12c, in 11.2 as far as I remember it must be dynamic SQL, not parameters).

Comment: @krokodilko I got a little bit confused right now by your comment. setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) translates to native FOR UPDATE. Same for .setFirstResult(pageIndex * noOfRecords) //
 .setMaxResults(noOfRecords) // which translates to OFFSET and LIMIT. The problem is how to dynamically join 2 queries written in JPA where inner query uses setFirstResult and setMaxResult and outer query uses setLockMode